# An 'expected an indent' error for no apparent reason

Tags: python

I was defining variables and when I was done it worked.  But, I went to the bottom to continue scripting, I tested it and it gave me an 'expected an indented block' error.  I don't know why.  Specifically, it gave it to me after I defined Right.
(piranha and hunger were defined earlier in the code)

```
def Left():
    piranha.left(90)
    piranha.forward(100)
    piranha.right(90)
    global hunger
    hunger = hunger - 5
    if hunger==0:

def Right():
    piranha.right(90)
    piranha.forward(100)
    piranha.left(90)
    global hunger
    hunger = hunger - 5
    if hunger==0:

def Back():
    piranha.right(180)
    piranha.forward(100)
    piranha.right(180)
    global hunger
    hunger = hunger - 5
    if hunger==0:
```

`

Comment: `if hunger == 0:` then what?

Comment: Your if-statements are incomplete. Generally, Python expects an indented block after a `:` (with few exceptions such as key-value mappings in `dicts`)

Answer (score 3):

You need to do something after the [if](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement)

For example:

```
if hunger==0:
    # Do something
    print("Dead piranha")  #Attention with the indentation, after ":" is indented
```

Also you can use:

```
hunger -= 5 # instead of hunger = hunger - 5
```

It does the same, but it is more clear.

Lastly, why do you use `global hunger`?
If you have a class that is `piranha`, I think it's a better idea to make a class attribute hunger.

```
piranha.hunger -= 5
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would be down to the if statements not being completed. Try adding a simple function to each statement.